# Running AHK Script

Tags: windows, loops, autohotkey

I have a simple loop script:

```
looper() {
    SendInput, {F5}
    Return  
}
SetTimer, looper, 10000
Return
```

When I try to start AHK file nothing is happening. But when I add random command script is runing:

```
looper() {
    SendInput, {F5}
        Return  
}
SetTimer, looper, 10000
Return
#1::
     sendInput test
return
```

Help xD.

Comment: See [#Persistent](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Persistent.htm).

Comment: I have been using AHK for a long time, but never needed to use that switch.
Thanks xD.